# Python Boolean method naming readability

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Which of these ways is more readable for Boolean Method in Python?

```
document.is_editable    
document.editable    
document.has_editable    
document.can_be_editable    
document.can_edit
```

Comment: We can definitely rule out the last 3, the first 2 are probably debatable so I'm not sure if this qualifies as a *constructive* question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would choose the first one (from the point of view of a Java developer).