# Python boolean methods naming convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm a Rubyist learning Python and I'm wondering if there is a convention in Python along the lines of the following.

In Ruby, methods that return booleans are supposed to always end in a `?`. For example,

```
def palindrome?(string)
  # some code that tests whether string is a palindrome
end
```

The only [existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214385/python-boolean-method-naming-readability) I can find speaking to this does not provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Since `?` is not allowed in Python function names, and since English `is` is restricted to (3rd person) singular present tense questions of being (as opposed to other verbs), I suggest we use a more general yes/no question marker from another language that doesn't suffer the same problems, such as Japanese "ka" suffix.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no standard naming convention specific to boolean-returning methods. However, PEP8 does have [a guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) for naming functions.

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Typically, people start a function with `is` (e.g. `is_palindrome`) to describe that a boolean value is returned.

Comment: It's strange that the makers of Python don't adhere to their own recommendation of using underscores to separate words...

Comment: @Kawu Not really strange. First version of Python was developed in the early 1990's and the conventions have been evolving since then. When you publish some API, you cannot just rename everything because "somebody had a great idea about new naming convention".

Answer (score 21):

I concur with [@CarolChen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996498/3357935) on the principle of turning to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python Style Guide, for guidance. I will suggest however that "as necessary to improve readability" is in the eye of the beholder. For example, each of these functions are used in Python either as functions of the `str` object or as builtin functions. These are as fundamental as it gets in the Python ecosystem and are good examples of a usage style focused on returning a boolean state AND having easily readable function names.

**str. methods**

```
isalnum()
isalpha()
isdecimal()
isdigit()
isidentifier()
islower()
isnumeric()
isprintable()
isspace()
istitle()
isupper()
```

**builtin functions:**

```
isinstance()
issubclass()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define it like

```
def is_palindrome(variable):
    # your logic\
    # return True / False
```